# Connecting to Casssandra on remote client using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have two PCs, one of them is Ubuntu system that has Cassandra, and the other one is Windows PC.
I have made same installations of Java, Spark, Python and Scala versions on both PCs. My goal is read data with Jupyter Notebook using Spark from Cassandra that on other PC.

On the PC that has Cassandra, I was able to read data with connecting to Cassandra using Spark. But when I try to connect that Cassandra from remote client using Spark, I could not connect to Cassandra and get an error.

[Representation of the system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7bvb.png)

Commands that run on Ubuntu PC which has Cassandra.

```
~/spark/bin ./pyspark --master spark://10.0.0.10:7077 --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.1.0 --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Xss512m --conf spark.executer.extraJavaOptions=-Xss512m

from spark.sql.functions import col

host = {"spark.cassandra.connection.host":'10.0.0.10,10.0.0.11,10.0.0.12',"table":"table_one","keyspace":"log_keyspace"}

data_frame = sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(**hosts).load()

a = data_frame.filter(col("col_1")<100000).select("col_1","col_2","col_3","col_4","col_5").toPandas()
```

As a result of the above codes running, the data received from Cassandra can be displayed.

---

Commands trying to get data by connecting to Cassandra from another PC.

```
import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = ' --master spark://10.0.0.10:7077 --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.1.0 --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Xss512m --conf spark.executer.extraJavaOptions=-Xss512m spark.cassandra.connection.host=10.0.0.10 pyspark '

import findspark
findspark.init()
findspark.find()

from pyspark import SparkContext SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

conf = SparkConf().setAppName('example')
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf = conf)
spark = SparkSession(sc)

hosts ={"spark.cassandra.connection.host":'10.0.0.10',"table":"table_one","keyspace":"log_keyspace"}

sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

data_frame = sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(**hosts).load()
```

As a result of the above codes running, " :java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html " error occurs.

What can I do for fixing this error?